# Android : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeHex

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I have added an external library from .jar in my project and whenever I run the the app, it throws this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.enginious.snowblossom, PID: 17643
>                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeHex(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
>                         at snowblossom.lib.SnowFieldInfo.(SnowFieldInfo.java:28)
>                         at snowblossom.lib.NetworkParamsTestnet.genSnowFields(NetworkParamsTestnet.java:32)
>                         at snowblossom.lib.NetworkParams.(NetworkParams.java:22)
>                         at snowblossom.lib.NetworkParamsTestnet.(NetworkParamsTestnet.java:13)
>                         at snowblossom.lib.NetworkParams.loadFromConfig(NetworkParams.java:96)
>                         at snowblossom.client.SnowBlossomClient.(SnowBlossomClient.java:281)
>                         at com.enginious.snowblossom.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

org.Appache.Commons is included in the library I have added but it is still throwing this error. I need guidance regarding this issue. Thanks.

Comment: i'm facing same issue even though i am using the latest version i.e 1.14 .